# Search in Youtube API by videoCategoryId

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I am trying to run the following call of the Youtube search API:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=10&order=relevance&relatedToVideoId=_CgRVkydY6Q&type=video&videoCategoryId=2&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

It returns 10 results, but some of them are not in category 2. For example, it gave me a result (ID: TG5e9Px3h-M) with videoCategoryId 22. I assume it does the search in the category ID with LIKE, not exact match.

How can I make this search with exact match for videoCategoryId?

Answer (score 1):

I think you cannot use `relatedToVideoId` and `videoCategoryId` at same time. **Related videos list for a particular video is fixed in youtube**. I have tried with 1,10,22,33,32 and 44 category id. But I got same result has I do not give `videoCategoryId` parameter. `videoCategoryId` is works when you search keyword and just give `type` parameter in api url.